# M2Mqtt failure to connect

Tags: asp.net, mqtt, m2m

I'm trying to implement this code to send a very simple

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("00.000.00.00");
client.Connect("client");
client.Publish("test", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("helloworld"));
client.Disconnect();
```

But I get this error:

> SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   00.000.00.00:1883

Does anyone know what caused the mistake and how to resolve it?
Alternatively, are there any other libraries for dotnet that would help me achieve the same goal (MQTTnet doesn't work either for whatever reason).

Thanks in advance anyone.

Comment: The error implies that there is no broker running on the target IP address

Comment: Try with this broker: `mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org')`

Comment: @hardillb , I actively use that same IP for other purposes so thee broker is running.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan , same results.

Comment: @MatteoBaldini: Can you please share the publisher and subscriber code?

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan The code above is used to publish messages. I use mqtt-spy as a placeholder publisher to test the network and I can receive messages sent by other clients written in other languages so I think it's more of a C# and dotnet issue.